# Modified knapsack problem with multiple boxes to choose from

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problems

I have seen the solution to the knapsack problem and understand it. But I am trying to
come up with a dynamic programming solution to the following problem, which is a modified
a version of the knapsack.
Consider a store with n boxes, each containing m items, and we could only choose  one
item out of each box, and the goal is to maximize the value of items, and there is only
one knapsack is available with volume V.

I am not sure how to begin to solve this using dynamic programming.

Comment: We're not looking for posts that are simply the statement of an exercise-style task and a request for us to solve it.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  If you don't know how to begin, then I suggest studying from a good textbook.  We also have resources on a systematic approach to d.p. exercises: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Answer (score 0):

For $i=0,\dots,n$ and $v=0, \dots V$ define $OPT[i,v]$ as the maximum value that can be attained by selecting at most one item from each of the first $i$ boxes (and no items from the remaining boxes) when the knapsack volume is $v$.

Let $v_{i,j}$ and $w_{i,j}$ be the value and the weight of the $j$-th item in the $i$-th box, respectively. Finally, for the sake of technical convenience, define $v_{i,0} = w_{i,0} = 0$.

You have:
$$
OPT[0,v] = 0 \; \forall v
$$
and, for $i \ge 1$:
$$
OPT[i, v] =  \max_{\substack{j=0, \dots, m \\ w_{i,j} \le v}} \left( v_{i,j} + OPT[i-1, v-w_{i,j}] \right).
$$

The optimal value for the original instance is $OPT[n,V]$. Moreover, the value of $OPT[i, v]$ can be found in time $O(m)$ once the values of $OPT[i-1, \cdot]$ are known. Therefore the overall running time is $O(mnV)$.